# angular.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am making a simple project using angular js.

**I am getting following error message in my chrome console.**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
bootstrap.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at app.js:1
```

Following is my **main.html**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="ContactApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Contacts: {{message}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>



     <script type="text/javascript"  src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"  src='bower_components/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"  src='bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
     <script src="src/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Following is my **server.js** file

```
const express = require("express");
var app =express();
app.use(express.static("./public"))
    .get("*",function(req,res){
        res.sendfile("public/main.html");
    })
    .listen(3000);
```

Following is my **app.js** file

```
var angularApp = angular.module("ContactApp",[]);
angularApp.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.message ="Hellow From Angular App.js";
});
```

**My System Directory structure of js files**[image]

**My VSCodeOnline Director Structure**[image]

**My Browser output with console**[image]

**My Try**

I thought that might be there would be some path issues so I simplified my path and created a lib folder and copied those three js file into that directory but still that did not work.What I am sure is that since I installed all these js libraries using bower thats why I am having these issues. 
What's the real reason behind this issue and how to resolve this. I have tried various other solutions on stackoverflow on similar issue but that did not work.

So is there some resolution to this or should I always use CDNs only?

**Updated**

My three js files

[Angular.min.js](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25396200/)[bootstrap.min.js](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25396202/)[jquery.min.js](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25396204/)

Comment: You have misplaced your jquery.js and bootstrap.js files just reverse(up-down) it

Comment: just did that but did not work

Comment: comment your script bootstrap.js and jquery.js file and tell me what your console says (just for debugging)

Comment: Chances are your `.js` files don't exist and your HTTP server is delivering a 404 page or something similar

Comment: @ChaitanyaGhule I commented that so all errors gone but since I did not comment app.js script so it said angular is not defined at app.js:1

Comment: just keep angular.js file and place app.js file below it

Comment: @Phil They do exists I copied them going to their physical location on my system and then pasted them for you. please see my updated post.

Comment: @ChaitanyaGhule same error although now only one unexpected token but same issue.

Comment: See sometimes it happens that in our .js file we might mistakenly place <script> tags check your app.js file for such unncessary script tag; due to which u get error like unexpected token < in app.js:1

Comment: @ChaitanyaGhule see my app.js file in post it just contains three lines.

Comment: ya i have seen it but just told u to verify; this error we mostly get due to syntax error known as unexpected token. o.w. try reinstalling those files again and if not just go for cdn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using the express static middleware incorrectly. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

You use the express static middleware to set the contents of "public" as static files like so:

```
app.use(express.static("./public"))
```

This assumes that in the same directory in which your node process is running, there is a folder called 'public'. If there were a file inside public called `image.jpg` then you would simply access it by doing `<img src="image.jpg>`.

But when you load the scripts on your server you try and get them from a folder called "bower_components". I'm assuming bower components is not inside your public folder.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Since your server can't find the script inside your public folder, it defaults to the next line which tells it to send main.html if it's not caught by anything else.

```
.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("public/main.html");
})
.listen(3000);
```

The issue is that the browser is expecting a js file, but is getting an html file that more than likely has a bunch of "<" in it and is throwing an error.

Try going to `localhost:3000/fjdlsfjd.js` and you should see that it still serves your main.html.

One way to fix this might be to also serve the `bower_components` folder.

```
app.use(express.static("relative/path/to/bower_components"))
```

And change the src attributes to reflect this change

```
src="jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
```

Or you can move every file you want to serve statically into your public directory.

Think of static middleware as doing something like

```
app.get("file.ext", func( req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/path/to/file.ext");
})
```

Except for every file in a given directory.

Comment: That is perfect and most beautifully explained answer. Thanks bro....Thank you very much Indeed.